# MSXML XSLT Parser Version

Tags: c++, msxml, msxml6, msxml3

I have a C++ app that uses msxml6.dll to read XML files and apply XSLTs.  I determined that MSXML v3.0 is being used for the XSLTs by including the following in one of my XSLT files:

```
<vendor><xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')"/></vendor>
<version><xsl:value-of select="system-property('ms:version')"/></version>
```

I don't understand why MSXML v3.0 is used instead of MSXML v6.0.  What needs to change for the app to use MSXML v6.0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating msxml object, specify the version explicitly. In vba it goes like this:

```
set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument.6.0")
```

Microsoft discourages using MSXML without specifying the version: [Why Version-Independent GUIDs and ProgIDs Were Removed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms761415%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: My C++ code is using CLSID_DomDocument instead of CLSID_DomDocument60.  Although I haven't tested changing it yet I believe that is the answer.